# Hotel Room Availability in Mysql Related tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a hotel room reservation application which is mainly based on below tables.

My reservations table,

```
`id`
`category`
`booking_no`
`room_id`
`date`
`guest_id`
`status`
```

My rooms table

```
`id`
`room_type_id`
`room_no`
`booking_no`
`blocked_from`
`blocked_to`
`status`
```

My room_types table

```
`id`
`category`
`name`
`status`
```

My check_inout table

```
`id`
`booking_no`
`room_id`
`guest_id`
`date`
`inout_status`
`status`
```

I am currently using below query to fetch available rooms which can add a reservation. This query works perfect and i can get what i want.

```
$query = "
SELECT r.room_type_id
     , r.id room_id
     , r.room_no
     , t.name room_type_name
  FROM rooms r
  JOIN room_types t
  ON t.id = r.room_type_id 
 WHERE r.id NOT IN 
( SELECT room_id 
       FROM reservations 
    WHERE (date >='$checkin' 
        AND date <'$checkout') 
       AND category = 'Accommodation' 
   AND status=1) 
   AND t.category = 'Accommodation' 
   AND r.status <> 7 
   AND (r.blocked_from > '$checkout' 
 OR r.blocked_to < '$checkin' 
     OR r.blocked_to IS NULL 
     OR r.blocked_from IS NULL) 
 ORDER 
    BY r.room_type_id
     , r.room_no ASC
";
```

Also, when guest checking in to the room i am inserting that status in to the table **check_inout** with status 1 for **inout_status** feild. And when he is checking out i am inserting status 2 for inout_status feild. Also i am updating booking number for particular room in the rooms table on checking-in, then remove it on checkout.

**Problem is:**
If one guest reserve a room for 1 day and if he checked out same day, (Ex: A guest checked in at 01:00 PM ~ checked out 06:00PM  same day), then room must be available for another guest to check-in.

Unfortunately i cannot get it using my table structure above. Because i am checking availability according to the reservations table using above query.

Help if someone can figure out a way to get it by linking **check_inout** table, since it has checking & checkout records for all rooms.

MySQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4747/2

In the result i want to get 204 room too, but i dont know how to get it.

Comment: If a guest checks out at 6.00pm, from when is the room then available? Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: it must available as soon as that guest checked-out.

Comment: That is a decidedly unusual setup. Anyway, get that data set and desired result up, and no doubt someone will be able to help

Comment: hint... you are storing days but you should also store times (hours). What about timestamps to store the bookings?

Comment: Cant i get a simple solution using a subquery with **check_inout** table ?